# How to read requests from har file with selenium webdriver using ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, selenium-webdriver

I am able to generate har file & save it on my machine. Now I want to read it and check specific logs available in that har file.

Please provide suggestion on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use following regex lines.

```
File.open(Dir["#{path}/*.har"][1], "r").each_line do |line|
  puts line if (line['https://your.domain.com'])
end
```

or

if you dont want regex then use

```
File.open(Dir["#{path}/*.har"][1], "r").each_line do |line|
  puts line if (line[/your.domain.com/])
end
```

Comment: `File.each_line('file.txt')` didn't work for me. It throws `NoMethodError: undefined method `each_line' for File:Class` Did this work for you? Rather `File.open("file.txt").each_line` works since this correct. Because you first have to open file before reading from or writing to it.